# PL/SQL Check constraint: value on one column depends on another column

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using PL/SQL, I'm building a table containing config which defines the distribution of samples into 2 different sets based on ratio. It has 4 columns: sample_type, set_1, set_2, ratio (percentage of samples going to set_1). For example, if a row is ('walk', 'left', 'right', 50), it means for samples whose type is 'walk', 50% of them goes 'left' while the rest goes 'right'.

I want to add a check constraint which makes sure that set_2 is null if only ratio is 100, i.e. 100% of sample goes to set_1. I try something like:

```
ALTER TABLE CONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK
CHECK (
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CONFIG WHERE SET_2 IS NULL AND RATIO <> 0)
)
```

However, Oracle doesn't allow sub-query in check. So, is there another way to add a check constraint for this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE CONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK
CHECK (
    (RATIO = 100) OR (SET_2 IS NOT NULL AND RATIO != 100)
)
```

and I wasn't completely sure if it was a requirement, but if SET_2 needs to be null in the case of 100, then you would want this:

```
ALTER TABLE CONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK
CHECK (
    (SET_2 IS NULL AND RATIO = 100) OR (SET_2 IS NOT NULL AND RATIO != 100)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would

```
ALTER TABLE CONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK
CHECK (
    SET_2 IS NULL AND RATIO <> 0
)
```

work?

Comment: It would force set_2 to be null and ratio to be non-zero all the time. I need a check that allow set_2 to be null if only ratio is 100, i.e. when ratio is not 100, set_2 must be not null

Comment: `ALTER TABLE CONFIG ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_SET_2 CHECK ( (SET_2 IS NULL AND RATIO = 100) OR (SET_2 IS NOT NULL AND RATIO <> 100) )`.